# why am getting NullPointerException on onActivityResult while relaunching the app?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onactivityresult, relaunch

I have a problem on onActivityResult method of an activity(Cordova activity), following is the case where this happens

1. Launch a Activity1
2. StartActivityForResult named Activity2
3. Press home button
4. Relaunch the app through clicking on app icon

am getting the splash activity called and then activity1 is called but this gives me nullpointerException on onActivityResult and the activity is not displaying the view as well.

Can anyone give me the solution to avoid this error?

```
<activity
        android:name=".MDLIVEMain"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Starting activity for result part

```
 Intent passcodeIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PasscodeActivity.class);
 passcodeIntent.putExtra("passcode_data_page",passcodeDataPage);
 startActivityForResult(passcodeIntent, PASSCODE_RESULT_PAGE);
```

OnaActivityResult code

```
     @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        CordovaPlugin callback = this.activityResultCallbacks;
        try {
            Log.d("onActivityResult",requestCode+"-"+responseCode+"");
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mConnectionResult = null;
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }

            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
            }
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if (requestCode == PASSCODE_RESULT_PAGE) {
                if (responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    activityVisible = true;
                    this.callbackContext.success(intent.getExtras().getString("passcode_pin"));
                } else {
                    this.callbackContext.success(intent.getExtras().getString("passcode_pin"));
                    isFromPasscodePage = true;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
//            finish();
        }
    }
```

Error come here

```
this.callbackContext.success(intent.getExtras().getString("passcode_pin"));
                isFromPasscodePage = true;
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: PLease post the error line

Answer (score 0):

`onActivityResult()` doesn´t work with `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, try deleting this property.

Comment: But i need to be included because while am relaunching this app from support app like Vsee the app should not get refresh so i made this.

Answer (score 0):

Dismissing a (progress) dialog in onActivityResult is questionable. onActivityResult is called after some other activity was active. In any case calling it from a runnable is unnecessary.

You are calling intent.getExtras().getString. There is no guarantee that the intent has extras or a string "passcode_pin" especially if the passcode activity was cancelled.

Comment: The app is relaunching, so why this onactivityresult is called ? because the app destroyed and started as fresh

Comment: Because you called startActivityForResult.

Comment: More specifically... An activity may have had its onDestroy called, but that does not mean the app was destroyed.